# Is there a difference between making a method synchronized or adding a synchronized block into the method?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Will these two code blocks behave equally? You may assume that those run methods are called from threads.

```
public synchronized void run() {
    System.out.println("A thread is running.");
}
```

Or

```
static Object syncObject = new Object();

public void run() {
    synchronized(syncObject) {
        System.out.println("A thread is running.");
    }
}
```

Comment: They lock different objects as @Eng.Fouad points out.  Right?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that article before posting (sorry).

Answer (score 6):

```
public synchronized void run()
{
    System.out.println("A thread is running.");
}
```

is equvalent to:

```
public void run()
{
    synchronized(this) // lock on the the current instance
    {
        System.out.println("A thread is running.");
    }
}
```

---

and for your information:

```
public static synchronized void run()
{
    System.out.println("A thread is running.");
}
```

is equvalent to:

```
public void run()
{
    synchronized(ClassName.class) // lock on the the current class (ClassName.class)
    {
        System.out.println("A thread is running.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one small note on this. I believe, having a synchronized method is a little bit more benefitial/defensive. It decreases a little bit chance that somebody unexperienced will add into method some code outside of synchronized block.

Comment: @VictorRonin +1 I agree.

Answer (score 0):

No, as you put it is no difference, but is the method would have been a static one, the synchronized block would have the class object of the enclosing class as the lock.